# Geocoding with OpenLayers, followed by manual map adjust and dynamic form update - possible?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geocoding

For an administration tool, I need to setup a form with the following functions:

- entering street, house number, zip code and city (in separate form fields); moreover in the form are two form fields for the lat and lon values
- "Geocode" button which will geocode the given address and display an inline map, centered on the found position (without sending the main form!) and setting the lat and lon values to the form fields
- the map should have a fixed "marker" at the center (not moving when panning or zooming the map) = to indicate exactly the center of the viewport
- the user should be able to pan the map, until the center ("marker") is exactly on the right position (it's necessary to adjust the location on +/- 2 meters exactly, so a simple geocoding request by the street address mostly fails = not precise enough)
- while panning the map, the values for lat and lon should be updated dynamically to the form fields
- after the position is adjusted, the form can be sent, and the values (incl. manually=graphically adjusted values for lat and lon) will be written to the database

Question: is it possible to do that with OpenLayers, and can someone help me to show the basic way to result? I searched several days for a working example, but couldn't find any. Google Maps API is no option because of usage restrictions and limits.

Comment: This is very vague question, you get more attention asking follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @MichalS thank you for your attention. But I don't see, why it's vague. I described precisely the workflow of the desired result, and asked how to do it resp. which tool/API or existing example can fit it. Unfortunately I didn't find some "copy&paste" example for it (like for other map apps), so I still don't have any code about which we might discuss.

Comment: hope you are right, and your question will not be left unanswered, but even if so, you can ask next one :) This is yours first one, and role of reviewers is to help you get into community. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible using OpenLayers. But keep in mind that OpenLayers is just a library for displaying map tiles and markers and consequently it cannot do geocoding itself. But you can use external geocoding services like for example [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), which is based on OpenStreetMap data.

OSM's Nominatim instance also has some [usage limits](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Usage_Policy), because it runs on donated resources. But there are two options: Either use a different instance like for example the [Nominatim instance provided by MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim) where the terms of use are less strict. Or [install your own Nominatim instance](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) which won't have any restrictions at all.